# React: How to pass down context to a component generated on runtime

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-native

I am trying to use the Modal for Android from mkonicek's gist https://gist.github.com/mkonicek/1a8bd7253e3257687228, it seems to show the modal properly, however it seems to crash when the child component accepts a context.

I'm assuming the reason is that the displayed component from the modal is not rendered using the `render` method so it does not pass the context information down.

Anyone knows how to pass down a context down to the rendered component inside the `_createModal`  https://gist.github.com/mkonicek/1a8bd7253e3257687228#file-modal-js-L90 function ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind found a way to do it using a ContextWrapper found the solution with the ReactRouter https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/982